# Customising the gmail compose page in android app

Tags: android, gmail

In my app I want the gmail customised compose page has to be opened and have to send a mail.

The page Should be customised as such the title bar colour ,the title and button should be changed according to need.

Using the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("mailto:" + "your_email"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your_subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your_text");
startActivity(intent);
```

opens the Gmail app's compose page.

I am searching this very long ago.Suggest me if there is any library to implement this android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.

The code you paste here can not even guarantee to launch a gmail client. That intent is only used to launch a email client, maybe k9-mail, maybe gmail, maybe else. And gmail app is not guaranteed to be installed on all Android devices.